# Uploading to amazon S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, next.js, buffer

I am trying to upload to s3. I have the form-data with the file in it. When I upload it I get 200 ok back but when I look at the file in the bucket it show a file there with no data in it. I think it has to do with the way I am sending the data.  here is my code;

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import {s3Client} from '@/utilites/s3Config'
import { PutObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";


export async function POST(request) {
    const formData = await request.formData()


   console.log(formData.get('file'))
   let file 
    file = formData.get('file')
   const name = formData.get('name')
   const type = formData.get('type')
   const size = formData.get('size')
   console.log(size)
   console.log(type)
   const year = formData.get('year')
   const month = formData.get('month')
   const description = formData.get('description')
   const category = formData.get('category')
 
   const awsParams = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `${category}/${year}/${name}`,
    Body:  Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(formData.get('file')))
   }

   const response = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(awsParams))

   console.log(response)

   return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({message: "ok"}))}
```

I know that the file has to be in a buffer that is about it. This is my first time trying to upload a file.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload a file using formData.get('file') and then converting it to a buffer using Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(formData.get('file'))). This might be causing issues with the actual file content. Instead, you can try to use the file stream directly from the form data without converting it to JSON. Also it's good practice to provide correct file metadata such as content type and content length. Try something like this,

```js
export async function POST(request) {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  const {
    file,
    name,
    type,
    size,
    year,
    month,
    description,
    category
  } = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

  // Convert the file data to a Readable stream
  const fileStream = new Readable();
  fileStream.push(file);
  fileStream.push(null);

  const awsParams = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `${category}/${year}/${name}`,
    Body: fileStream,  // Use the Readable stream as the Body,
    ContentType: type,
    ContentLength: size
  };

  try {
    const response = await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(awsParams));
    console.log(response);

    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ message: "ok" }));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading to S3:", error);
    return new NextResponse(JSON.stringify({ error: "Upload failed" }), {
      status: 500
    });
  }
}
```

Or with buffer if you prefer. like this,

```js
// Read the contents of the File object into a Buffer
  const fileData = await file.arrayBuffer();
  const buffer = Buffer.from(fileData);

  const awsParams = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
    Key: `${category}/${year}/${name}`,
    Body: buffer,  // Use the Buffer as the Body
    ContentType: type,
    ContentLength: size
  };
```

Comment: so when I tried to do the upload direct like this I received the following error which I have been reciving? Error uploading to S3:  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of File

Comment: Apologies, forgot to add stream logic and added the file in the body instead. I have updated my answer. sorry.